# CASE not working properly in SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, case

I'm having an issue with using the `CASE` statement to change my `ORDER BY` statement in a stored procedure.

I'm sending in a parameter, `@sortBy`, which contains the name of the column to order by.

My issue is that the `CASE` statement works for most of the columns, but not others:

```
SELECT * FROM TapeView
                ORDER BY
                    CASE
                        WHEN @sortBy = 'BackupJobType' THEN [BackupJobType]
                        WHEN @sortBy = 'ItemID' THEN [ItemID]
                        WHEN @sortBy = 'MediaType' THEN [MediaType]
                        WHEN @sortBy = 'Category' THEN [Category]
                        WHEN @sortBy = 'Description' THEN [Description]
                        WHEN @sortBy = 'PlantName' THEN [PlantName]
                        WHEN @sortBy = 'BackupType' THEN [BackupType]
                        WHEN @sortBy = 'UserID' THEN [UserID]
                    END
```

For some reason, this works fine for every column except for `BackupJobType` and `Description`.

I have checked the value of the parameter being sent in and the names of the columns, and am 100% certain that they are correct.

I have a nearly-identical query on another page and both of these columns are working fine there.

Any ideas?

Edit: I forgot to mention that all of these columns are varchar datatypes

Comment: Post some sample output to show us how it is not working.

Comment: The reason probably has to do with all the columns having to be converted to the same type.  Without examples, it is hard to say exactly what is happening.

Comment: The how is it not working question still applies.

Comment: @McFixit Is the `@sortBy` parameter anything smaller than varchar(11), perhaps varchar(10)?  If so then "Description" becomes "Descriptio" and "BackupJobType" becomes "BackupJobT", but the other column names fit. If this is the case, bump up the `@sortBy` data type to something like varchar(50).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the datatype of the `@sortBy` stored procedure parameter or local variable is anything smaller than the length of "Description", i.e. varchar(11), then that is your problem.  For example, if `@sortBy` is varchar(10), then "Description" becomes "Descriptio" (first 10 chars) and "BackupJobType" becomes "BackupJobT", but the other column names fit. If this is the case, change the `@sortBy` data type of the procedure parameter and/or local variable to varchar(128).

Comment: Well that was one of the dumber mistakes I've made in a while, that was it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably caused by types.  I would expect the `id`s to be a problem too, if they are numeric.

Putting each condition in a separate clause should fix the problem:

```
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN @sortBy = 'BackupJobType' THEN [BackupJobType] END),
         (CASE WHEN @sortBy = 'ItemID' THEN [ItemID] END),
         (CASE WHEN @sortBy = 'MediaType' THEN [MediaType] END),
         (CASE WHEN @sortBy = 'Category' THEN [Category] END),
         (CASE WHEN @sortBy = 'Description' THEN [Description] END),
         (CASE WHEN @sortBy = 'PlantName' THEN [PlantName] END),
         (CASE WHEN @sortBy = 'BackupType' THEN [BackupType] END),
         (CASE WHEN @sortBy = 'UserID' THEN [UserID] END)
```

The clauses that don't match will all product `NULL`s, so they will not affect the ordering.

Comment: I'll try this when I get the chance, however I should have pointed out that this is a smaller subset of a larger query which has IF statements to sort out the different data types.  Everything in this list is a varchar type

Comment: @McFixit . . . Well, the types of the columns are not the issue.  My next suspicion is that your expectation of what the ordering should be is wrong.  Can you edit your question and provide an example of the sort being off?